# Swift: same function in two extensions, different modules

Tags: ios, swift, module, extension-methods

When developing an app, I use extensions to hide a dependency on a particular library in my code. I'd like the method names to be exactly the same as in the library.

This approach helps greatly reduce dependency on the external library (to swap it with a different one I'll need only to rewrite functions in the bridge). However, it's a little bit tricky in case of extensions, as I get infinite loop with this code:

```
// Library implementation, File1.swift
import Foundation
extension Date {
  func test(otherDate: Date) -> String {
    return String()
  }
}


// App reference to the library, different module, File2.swift
import Foundation
import Library
extension Date {
  func test(otherDate: Date) -> String {
    // How to reference "Library" here?
    return test(otherDate: otherDate)
  }
}
```

When adding a prefix, the approach works fine:

```
// Works correctly:
import Foundation
import Library
extension Date {
  func prefix_test(otherDate: Date) -> String {
    return test(otherDate: otherDate)
  }
}
```

**Is there any way in Swift to call an extension method from a particular module, similar to selecting a class**:

```
// Selecting a class:
let a = Module1.CustomClass()
let b = Module2.CustomClass()

let date = Date()

// Can I select an extension method?
date.Module1.func1()
date.Module2.func1()
```

**How is this question different from the "duplicate":**
In case of class functions it is possible to do:

```
Module1.Class1.classFunction()
Module2.Class1.classFunction()
```

**In the aforementioned case, such call is impossible, hence the question.**

Comment: The duplicate is still valid, since the third part of the answer explains that the namespace of extensions is the extended class, so you cannot do what you want. You can also use "way1" from the duplicate; different extension function names

Comment: The 2nd duplicate is exactly what I was looking for. Still, there is no answer to this question so far (at least in Swift 4.1 Xcode 9.4)

Comment: There is an answer. You can't do it for the reason that I explained; the namespace of an extension is the extended class

Comment: Exactly. What I meant is "There is no answer to achieve such a result... yet"

Comment: There is nothing in Swift Evolution that proposes changing the namespace that applies to an extension. I guess you could propose it at Swift.org. [This project](https://github.com/holysin/Extensions) uses a protocol to provide a namespace for extensions; you could adopt that

Comment: Thanks for the info about Swift Evolution. For now I'm fine with the prefix.